# Element spanning columns in a column-filled grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm building a grid of elements, and each element has an expandable details box that should take up space in the row below it.

Here it is in action:

```js
const grid = document.querySelector('.item-grid');
for( let i=0; i<26; i++) {
  let letter = String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0)+i);
  let dt = document.createElement('dt');
  dt.setAttribute("tabindex","0");
  dt.append(letter);
  let dd = document.createElement('dd');
  dd.append(`Description for ${letter}`);
  grid.append(dt,dd);
}
```

```css
.item-grid {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
  align-items: start;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 66px);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(66px, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}
.item-grid>dt {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  align-self: stretch;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.item-grid>dd {
  display: none;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.item-grid>dt:focus+dd {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<dl class="item-grid"></dl>
```

This works perfectly. However, I now want to change the design to use longer text labels, and be sorted in column form, ie. top-to-bottom before left-to-right.

I figured changing `grid-auto-flow` to `column dense` instead of `row dense` would achieve the effect I want, but unfortunately... well, take a look.

```js
const grid = document.querySelector('.item-grid');
for( let i=0; i<26; i++) {
  let letter = String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0)+i);
  let dt = document.createElement('dt');
  dt.setAttribute("tabindex","0");
  dt.append(Array.from({length:10}).join(letter));
  let dd = document.createElement('dd');
  dd.append(`Description for ${letter}`);
  grid.append(dt,dd);
}
```

```css
.item-grid {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
  align-items: start;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 200px);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(66px, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column dense;
}
.item-grid>dt {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  align-self: stretch;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.item-grid>dd {
  display: none;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.item-grid>dt:focus+dd {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<dl class="item-grid"></dl>
```

I have also tried just using `column-*` CSS properties along with `column-span: all`, however this changes the order of elements when a description box is shown, rather than just expanding space downwards.

Theoretically I can use JavaScript to rearrange the elements into the right order based on window size, but that would need updating when the browser window is resized and besides it would knacker screen-readers and the tab order. I'd prefer a CSS-only option.

Comment: for a column flow you need to define a number of rows

Comment: columns can help here: https://jsfiddle.net/y9orbjpf/ but still not perfect

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yup, what you've done in that Fiddle is exactly what I tried when I attempted `column-*` CSS. The big issue is that when you expand say E then elements A-D are moved to be above the cut and F-Z below, which is a very undesirable effect here.